# insert update delete in mysql with single query

Tags: mysql

I have two table source and target. Is it possible to perform following operation in single query?

- If the row exists in both the source and target, UPDATE the target;
- If the row only exists in the source, INSERT the row into the target;
- If the row exists in the target but not the source,
  DELETE the row from the target.

Comment: Yes!, thats possible, let us know.. what you have tried.

Comment: The first two can be done in a single INSERT with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause. I don't think the DELETE can be done in that query as well.

Comment: @Rafee I tried first two using 'insert' with 'on duplicate key update' clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it all in one query, but you can do it all in one transaction if you are using a transactional store engine (like InnoDB). This might be what you want,

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT...;
DELETE...
UPDATE...;

COMMIT;